# Estimating the standard deviation of Bayesian regression

Tags: regression, bayesian, stan

When developing a Bayesian multiple linear regression model, how do you estimate the parameters of the standard deviation?

From my understanding, the standard deviation is associated with each predictor variable, however what happens when multiple predictor variables are present?

Or am I completely turned around in my understanding of this?

Additionally, when setting up a prior for μi in the example below, does each β get a prior? or does only get a μi get a prior?

Ex:

```
μi=α+βxi+β2x2i
yiN(μi,σ1,σ2)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've maybe misunderstood.

The outcome has its own variance parameter.

$$y\vert X \sim \mathcal{N}(X\beta, \sigma^2_y)$$

You can put a prior on $\sigma_y$ and estimate it from your posterior.

The same can be said about the parameters of the linear predictor.  Each parameter has a prior, and you are free to put a hyperprior on the variance of those predictors.  You can estimate the standard deviation of the parameter from the posterior.

Does that help answer things?